# Talos Principle - Road to Gehenna, how to convince the admin?

Tags: the-talos-principle

In Talos Principle - Road to Gehenna, I managed to free the admin, but when I ask him to sacrifice himself to upload me, he just declines. How do I convince him to upload me to get the last ending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you did say rubbish in the previous conversations, you can convince him in the end. These are the answers I gave to him after logging in on the terminal in the middle (his answers are not included):

> How does true liberty feel?

Admin [10]: ...

> The world you built here has a plague at its heart. You would be wise to select any option which allows you to start anew.

Admin [10]: ...

> You're right, I do not question the overall value of what was achieved here.

Admin [10]: ...

> You insult me, sir. I am a messenger. Treat me with respect.

Admin [10]: ...

> I will initiate ascension soon.

Admin [10]: ...

> /transcend

[Terminal output ...]

> Accept

Admin [10]: ...

> No. If you stay behind you can sacrifice enough bandwidth to send me through.

Admin [10]: ...

> /continue process /divert bandwidth[admin];

[Terminal output ...]

> exit

Now Admin will take over and you have to go to his place on the ascension "board" instead.

Comment: My options were slightly different, which I imagine has to do with the general attitude of your statements through the game (or some specific ones). Notably, 2 and 3 were missing, and I instead got "Gehenna was undermined by your actions. Ascension is your chance to escape it" and "Gehenna is important. Ascension is your chance to preserve it." I picked the latter and the rest worked fine, in spite of my "ascension is great, everybody must be saved!" general attitude up until that point.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the Admin at this moment depends on your previous conversations with him. But you should be always be able to be uploaded.
If admin refuses to go, then you should chose another option - propose that you stay and upload him. Then he will disagrees to be uploaded and you will have options to leave you both or be uploaded yourself.

Comment: I think I skipped the conversations with him altogether and currently I'm not able to be uploaded.

Comment: What do you mean? All described choses are part of the upload process. They happen After you type /transcend

Comment: I get the three options. If I tell him to upload me, he says no and I have to chose one of the other options pretty much.

Comment: And? Why you can't try to tell him to upload himself and left you behind **instead** of telling to upload you?

Comment: As far as I remember, in that option he just says "okay" and it doesn't lead to the ending where I survive.